# Combination with multiple values in list - creation of sublists

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, algorithm, sublist

I have the following issue:

```
nums = [2, 4, 2, 10, 5]
```

I want to achieve some sublists where the rule is presented below:

```
sublist = [[2], [2,4], [2,4,2], [2,4,2,10], [2,4,2,10,5], [4], [4,2], [4,2,10], [4,2,10,5] ... ]
```

My code:

```
def combinator(nums, N):

    for i in range(2**N):
        combo = []
        for j in range(N):
            if (i >> j) % 2 == 1:
                combo.append(nums[j])

        yield combo
```

and

```
out = []
N = len(nums)
for i in combinator(nums, N):
    out.append(i)
```

The code generates an unwanted list with all combinations.
How I can improve the code?

Comment: What is the "_unwanted list_"? Also, why is `[2, 4, 2]` not included?

Comment: One more question: following your logic, there may be two lists `[2]`. Do you want to keep both of them? And what is `N`?

Comment: Are you looking for a function that takes a list and returns a list of all sublists that have elements that were adjacent in the original list, in the same order?

Comment: Typos, thanks. I reformated the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function that takes a list and returns a list of all sublists that have elements that were adjacent in the original list, in the same order:

```
def sublists(xs):
    return [xs[n:m+1] for n in range(len(xs)) for m in range(n, len(xs))]


print(sublists([2, 4, 2, 10, 5]))
```

Result:

```
[[2], [2, 4], [2, 4, 2], [2, 4, 2, 10], [2, 4, 2, 10, 5], [4], [4, 2], [4, 2, 10], [4, 2, 10, 5], [2], [2, 10], [2, 10, 5], [10], [10, 5], [5]]
```

Comment: Amazing Pythonic solution... Thank you!